# Distinct count function for @[CustomerID] column counting @[CustomerNames] in excel

Tags: excel, dax, distinct, powerpivot

CustomerID is the primary key which I' using (number format).
First thing which I did was insert a new column to count if a particular CustomerID have been occured more than once
`@CountOfInvoices =COUNTIFS(@[CustomerID],G2)`

Then I created a power pivot table and the first column I inserted was @CountOfInvoices

I added a measure for the second column which was
`@CountOfDistinctCustomerIDs = DISTINCTCOUNT(CustomerID)`

There was no error in the DAX formula but the result were calculating distinct count for CustomerNames instead of CustomerID, I thought the problem might be with formatting so I rechecked but still the problem remains.

I'm very new to power pivot and DAX structure so if I could get an explanation for the issue would be very helpful

Comment: If you are on `Microsoft-365` then you can do it using formulas only with combination of few formulas.

Comment: excel 2016 on my personal pc and office 365 at work